Change order of personal data in moderncv
Previous questions stuggling with the same issues have somehow not solved my problem, so I am asking again: I would like to change to order of personal data entries in moderncv. I use the classic template.
Currently, it appears as
ADDRESS
BIRTHDATE
EMAIL
WEBSITE
ORCHID
Updates
I would like the birthdate to appear first. Everything else is fine.
Here is my current preamble:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[hyperref]{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm} 
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{FIRST}
\familyname{LAST} 

\born{BIRTHDATE}
\email{EMAIL}
\social[orcid]{...}
\homepage{WEBSITE}
\address{ADDRESS}
\extrainfo{Updated: 22/DEC/2024}

Can anyone help with this?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

This patch will make the date of birth appear first.

Used moderncv.cls    2024-07-18 v2.4.1
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[hyperref]{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm} 
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}

%***************************************************** added
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}
{\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\makenewline\bornsymbol\@born}}
{\relax}
{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}
{\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}}
{\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\makenewline\bornsymbol\@born}\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}}
{}{}
\makeatother
%***************************************************** 
    
\firstname{FIRST}
\familyname{LAST} 

\born{BIRTHDATE}
\email{EMAIL}
\social[orcid]{...}
\homepage{WEBSITE}
\address{ADDRESS}
\extrainfo{Updated: 22/DEC/2024}

\begin{document}
    
    \makecvtitle
        
    \section{Education}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}


Amazing, thank you so much! This worked.
